# Template specialization within template definition: is this supported for all compilers or standard usage?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

This compiled on VS 2008, but it seems like non-standard usage of templates.

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
public:
  void bar(Foo<int> arg)
  {
    // do some stuff here
  }

  // more code ...
};
```

Is there an issue since the template specialization `Foo<int>` is contained within the definition of its own template class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really specialisation - you are just saying that function takes a parameter of type `Foo <int>` - the fact that the function is itself a member of the Foo class isn't really important. And yes, it's legal.

Comment: He was using the correct term, though. `Foo<int>` is a class template specialization reference (generated specialization when instantiated, but can be a reference to an explicit specialization). But i suspect, like you, that he was meaning explicit specializations, but accidentally confused it with the general template specialization term. That's what we get from C++'s complex definitions :)

Comment: @Johannes You are right of course, but I think most people would refer to it (possibly wrongly) as an instantiation. Anyway, my use of the word "really" as intended to cover all bases :-)